# A James Bond Mystery

Tags: riddle, knowledge

Inspired by @[DEEM](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/34419/deem)'s amazing Grandpa Puzzles, I decided to make my own (ran out of ideas for the title so I just picked *James Bond*)

---

So, one day you meet the famous **James Bond** and since you are a huge fan, you asked him the things that he liked and didn't like. Surprisingly, he said this :

> I like to lead, but I don't like the number 2
>
> I like bears, but I don't like knights
>
> I like to be mean, but for some odd reason, I don't like the sun
>
> I like to lie to others, but I don't like to be frank

So, what is the reason behind his liking and disliking of random things?

Note :

> Will give more examples as hints in the future

Comment: If Cashbee's answer is correct, I would like to point out that (rot13) yrnq - ryrzrag Co naq yrq ner ubzbcubarf fb ur fubhyqa'g yvxr yrnq.

Comment: Well, that wasn't intended really :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

James Bond likes

> Homographs

and dislikes

> Homophones

Because

> *lead, bears, mean, lie* - are all homographs, while 2 (to), knights (nights), sun (son) and frank (Frank) are homophones. Homographs have multiple meanings, and James Bond likes them because *he doesn't like to be frank* :)

Comment: Well, you are right but are you sure your explanation is correct :)

Comment: Lol, you're missing something small yet quite big :D

Comment: Yes, you are stretching very far away and your hunch is correct :D

Comment: Gonna give u a small hint : Don't forget to check meanings...what can I possibly be talking about?

Comment: @KevinL Does your refusal have something to do with rot(Ubzbalzf if Ubzbcubarf)

Comment: Yes it does. :D

Comment: (Don't decrypt this if u don't want to know the answer) Just gonna say ROT13 (Jung ur qvfyvxrf nera'g ubzbalzf, gurl'er ubzbcubarf)

Comment: @KevinL lol damn my non-nativeness and my translator, of course I meant that..

Comment: That's a surprise. Btw, it wasn't as complicated as you thought so erase the last part :D

Comment: @KevinL thanks, that is nice to hear :) I'll also remove some of my comments here

Comment: @Cashbee OK, gonna accept ur answer tomorrow :D

Answer (score 8):

Another try. I think James Bond likes

> Words that can be anagrammed that is not a plural?

Proof

> `lead -> deal`,`bears -> saber`,`mean -> name`,`lie -> lei` (**lei**: a Polynesian garland of flowers) 
>  
>  `number two`,`knights`,`frank` can't be anagrammed, `sun -> nus` but `nus` is a plural

Comment: Unfortunately, incorrect :D

Comment: @KevinL Please add more words that disqualify this rule. (Lol, noticed my rep is 2,018)

Comment: Will do :D Nice reputation (will upvote so that it becomes 2023 lol) :)

Comment: Still not the answer :)

Comment: What about "tow"?

Answer (score 6):

Possibly

> He likes words that have 2 (or more) meanings/ambiguity.
>  Lead, bear, mean and lie all have more than 1 meaning
>  The number 2, knights, sun and frank(?) are all concrete concepts

Comment: Close but not correct :D

Answer (score 5):

I think he likes

> Friends and enemies, allies and foes

But not

> help or fights, wars or conflicts

That's because he likes

> words with two vowels next to each other

Comment: Welcome T Dude!  nice answer!

Comment: Interesting answer but unfortunately incorrect :D