# James Bond Is Coming Back Again!

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I wanted to make another one of my [James Bond Puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72260/a-james-bond-mystery) so here it is!

---

One evening when you ate together with the famous James Bond in an ultra fancy and hyper expensive restaurant (he was the one paying of course), he suddenly said :

> You know what? For some reason,
>
> I like Math, but I don't like Physics
>
> I like Chemistry, but I don't like Biology
>
> I also like pens, but I hate papers
>
> Oh and I almost forgot, I also don't like rocks

So, what is the reason behind his liking and disliking of random things?

Hint :

> Is it really all about letters here?

Hint 2 :

> Don't forget to check the numbers Wait, what numbers???

Comment: When I read "I like pens" I read something else... xD $(+1)$

Comment: Dude I didn't mean that one lol XD @user477343

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr Bond may be fond of

> Theory or things that require you to deduce and think about.

He may not like

> Things that have a rigidity around them or a physical presence. Physics deal with how objects interact with the space and there is also the rigid body we use in calculations. Biology aka living matter which have a physical presence and so do rocks.

Now

> About the pen and paper, here is how I interpret it as. The pen's use is to write and we write on papers. So unless a pen is being used to write, it has no significance other than aesthetics. When it is used on paper, it leaves a physical trace i.e the ink on the paper which is why he does not like it.

Another interpretation can be

> Mr Bond likes aesthetics. To some, mathematical formulas and chemical formulas look beautiful. So does a pen. Whereas Biology, Physics and paper are fascinating but aren't exactly what one would consider as beautiful (speaking in terms of the strictly mathematical geekiness here. And Physics problems have math in them. Also look at a paper under a microscope, it's not so smooth as it seems)

Attempt 2 **The Correct Answer**

> Mr Bond likes things which contain total number of letters that are perfect squares. Math = 4 , Chemistry = 9 , pens = 4 letters each which are perfect squares of 2 and 3. Whereas Biology = 7, physics = 7, rocks = 5, papers = 6 which are not perfect squares of anything. This can also be interpreted as Mr Bond likes words with a total number of letters that have a whole integer value as their square root i.e 2 and 3 as stated above.

Comment: Good answer but still incorrect :D

Comment: Ah well. The last line about the rocks is bugging me a bit.

Comment: Well, I made that last line since @obl's answer was correct with the old version of the question (Although that wasn't intended) :D

Comment: The one about rocks I mean. It's the odd one out here.

Comment: Oh, yeah I see. Nevertheless, nice try :)

Comment: @KevinL Attempt 2 has been made

Comment: Hell yeah, you're absolutely 100% correct. Will give the checkmark tomorrow :D

Comment: Wait, who's first (you or Luke C. J. Currie) ?

Comment: @KevinL me lol. I answered as soon as you gave the hint

Answer (score 5):

James likes

> Words whose numerical values add up to an even number
>  Math = 13 + 1 + 20 + 8 = 42
>  Physics = 16 + 8 + 25 + 19 + 9  + 3 + 19 = 99
>  Chemistry = 120
>  Biology = 85
>  pens = 54
>  paper = 75

Comment: Oh nice answer but still not right :)

Answer (score 4):

James Bond doesn't like

> Words with repeated letters in them

Explanation

> Phy**s**ic**s**, Bi**o**l**o**gy, **p**a**p**ers

Also

> **James Bond** doesn't have any repeated letters

Comment: Nope that's not the reason :D

Comment: I've added another line to clarify that yours is not the intended one. Nice try though (+1)

Answer (score 3):

My guess is:

> James is a chemical engineering Graduate student.

Because:

> He likes math, but doesn't like applying it. He chose Chemistry because Biology seemed boring, and he hates academic papers. But all Graduate Assistants need a good red pen for grading.

Comment: James Bond also known to cause lots of explosions

Comment: @Namyts That he is.

Comment: Way off track but still a nice answer :D

Comment: @KevinL Im sorry, I coulden't resist.

Comment: @Dylan No problem mate since I like creative answers (like yours) :D

Answer (score 2):

James Bond like words whose

> length is a perfect square.

and dislikes words whose

> length is not a perfect square.

Explanation

> Math is 4 letters long. Chemistry is 9. Pens is 4. Both 4 and 9 are perfect squares (of 2 and 3)

But

> Physics is 7 letters long as is Biology. Papers is 6 letters and rocks is 5. None of those numbers are perfect squares.

Comment: Correct answer but I don't know who answered first? You or R.D. ???

Comment: Looks like R.D. got it about 20 minutes before I did. Haha didn't even see his edit before.

Comment: Ok thanks for telling me. Still, yours was a perfect answer mate :D

Comment: @LukeC.J.Currie Fastest finger first I guess XD. +1 Nevertheless. Better luck next time.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that

> He likes the formulation of tools used for subjects, but dislikes the subjects which apply those tools.

Because:

> Maths is the main tool for Physics. Chemistry is a main tool for Biology. Pens are a main tool used for paper.

But I really hope I'm wrong! Since the above doesn't take into account:

> Physics is a main tool for chemistry (eg: for calculating electron orbital shapes)

Although knowing me, I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely... :)

Comment: Not the correct answer :D